# Tidyverse Rowwise sum of columns that may or may not exist

Tags: r, sum, tidyverse, rowwise

Consider the following tibble:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(x = c(rnorm(5,2,n = 10)*1000,NA,1000),
               y = c(rnorm(1,1,n = 10)*1000,NA,NA))
```

Suppose I want to make a row-wise sum of "x" and "y", creating variable "z", like this:

```
data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(z = sum(c(x,y), na.rm = T))
```

This works fine for what I want, but the problem is that my true dataset has many variables and I did not
want to check before what variables I have and what I do not have. So, suppose I may have variables that do not exist among the elements of the sum:

```
data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(k = sum(c(x,y,w), na.rm = T))
```

In this case, it will not run, because column "w" does not exist.
How can I make it run anyway, ignoring the non-existence of "w" and summing over "x" and "y"?

PS: I prefer to do it without filtering the dataset before running the sum. I would like to somehow make the sum happen in any case, whether variables exist or not.

Comment: You can use `across()` from `dplyr` and set the start and end variables!

Comment: In my case, I have a specific list of, like 130 columns I want to sum over a total of 300 columns... but this is not a problem, I have the specified lists already stored in vectors. The thing is that this list has columns that do not exist in my dataset, and I want to ignore then instead of "cleaning the lists".

Comment: Maybe `res <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Sum=sum(c_across(yourlistofvariables),na.rm=T))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understood your problem correctly this would be a solution (slight modification of @Duck's comment:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(x = c(rnorm(5,2,n = 10)*1000,NA,1000),
               y = c(rnorm(1,1,n = 10)*1000,NA,NA),
               a = c(rnorm(1,1,n = 10)*1000,NA,NA))


wishlist <- c("x","y","w")


data %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Sum=sum(c_across(colnames(data)[colnames(data) %in% wishlist]),na.rm=T))

       x      y       a   Sum
   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 3496.   439.   -47.7 3935.
 2 6046.   460.  2419.  6506.
 3 6364.   672.  1030.  7036.
 4 1068.  1282.  2811.  2350.
 5 2455.   990.   689.  3445.
 6 6477.  -612. -1509.  5865.
 7 7623.  1554.  2828.  9177.
 8 5120.   482.  -765.  5602.
 9 1547.  1328.   817.  2875.
10 5602. -1019.   695.  4582.
11   NA     NA     NA      0 
12 1000     NA     NA   1000
```

Comment: Hi @DPH this solves the problem, but the only issue is that in your example, the wishlist has the names of variables as strings, but I was using the notation c(x,y) without quotation marks. This is because my input (wishlist) is a chunk of text like "x,y,z" that I'm just pluggin in the formula. Is there a way to keep this notation or apply quotation marks at once in all elements of the wishlist?

Comment: you could try this with your input string: whishlist <- stringr::str_split(c("x,y,z"), pattern = ",")[[1]]

Comment: I figured it out here. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(x = c(rnorm(5,2,n = 10)*1000,NA,1000),
               y = c(rnorm(1,1,n = 10)*1000,NA,NA))

data$k <- rowSums(as.data.frame(data[,which(c("x","y","w")%in%names(data))]),na.rm=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
       x     y     k
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 3121.  934. 4055.
 2 6523. 1477. 8000.
 3 5538.  863. 6401.
 4 3099. 1344. 4443.
 5 4241.  284. 4525.
 6 3251. -448. 2803.
 7 4786. -291. 4495.
 8 4378.  910. 5288.
 9 5342.  653. 5996.
10 4772. 1818. 6590.
11   NA    NA     0 
12 1000    NA  1000
```